# Picture Justification of $\arccos(x) = \int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Is there a quick shortcut way to write down that
$$\arccos(x) = \int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$$
[just using the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q2j4.gif)?
I know it can be computed with a computation using $\theta = \frac{s}{r}$ and 
$$\theta = \frac{s}{1} = \int_0^s ds' = \int_x^1 \sqrt{1+y'}dt = \int_x^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)^2}dt = ... = \int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$$
but it should be obvious without any calculation right? Don't see / forget how to justify it. The main issue is justifying the 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$
term.

Comment: Yes https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/2/f/c/2fc99919298a20d95e2b585386fcbee2.png $\arcsin(x)$ goes from $0$ to $x$ then, as in the picture, $\arccos(x)$ goes from $x$ to $1$, something I thought was very cool since I'd never seen this nice picture before, and am asking about $\arctan$ etc in a moment.

Comment: @Dr.MV One way to define trigonometric functions from first principles is to take as your first definition the integral definition of $\arccos(x)$ as I've given above, where you justify the integrand from the arc length argument I've given. I'm asking for a quick clever way to justify that the arc length of a circle can be written as I've asked *before* we even know what trig functions are, i.e. without assuming $\frac{d}{dt}\arccos(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$. The main problem is looking at the picture and intuitively seeing why we must integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$

Comment: http://qr.ae/RwQOuA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Heuristic Development:**

I'm not sure if there is a quick way to derive the integral representation for the arccosine function.  But here is a way we can proceed using the "picture" and applying heuristic reasoning.

Draw an incremental segment of length $ds$ at a point on the circle at angle $s$; this segment is tangent to the circle. Then draw a small right triangle with sides $dx$ and $dy$, parallel to the $x$-axis and $y$-axis, respectively.  Denote the angle that $dx$ makes with $ds$ by $\gamma$.

Then, note that the differential arc length $ds$ can be expressed as a projection onto the $x$-axis as

$$ds=\frac{dx}{\cos \gamma}$$

But, we can easily see that $\cos \gamma =\sin (s) =\sqrt{1-x^2}$.  And we have

$$ds=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

---

**Rigorous Approach:**

I thought it might be instructive to present a purely analytical approach (i.e., one that needs no "picture.") that relies only on knowledge of the cosine function and its derivative.

We have

$$f(x) = \cos (x)\implies f^{-1}(x)=\arccos (x)$$

Then, using [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation) relationship of the derivative of an inverse function we have

$$f'(x)=-\sin x=-\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}\implies (f^{-1})'(x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \tag 1$$

Now, integrating $(1)$ we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt&=-\int_x^1 (f^{-1})'(t)\,dt\\\\
&=-\int_x^1 \frac{d\arccos(t)}{dt}\,dt\\\\
&=\arccos(x)-\arccos(1)\\\\
&=\arccos(x)
\end{align}$$

And of course, we could work backwards by starting with the arccosine written as

$$\arccos(x)=-\int_x^1 \frac{d\arccos(t)}{dt}\,dt$$

Then, using $(1)$, we arrive at the coveted result.

---

**NOTE:**

If we use the notion of arc length to derive the arccosine, then we proceed as follows.

The equation for the upper-half of the circle is given by $y(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, for $-1< x<1$.  Then, the arc length for an arc that subtends $s$ can be written

$$\begin{align}
s&=\int_0^s ds'\\\\
&=\int_{\cos s}^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx'}\right)^2}\,dx'\\\\
&=\int_{\cos s}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x'^2}}\,dx' \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Then, letting $s=\arccos(x)$ in $(1)$ reveals that

$$\arccos(x)=\int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x'^2}}\,dx'$$

Comment: This is basically just restating what I've written in my question :\

Comment: I am happy to delete this answer if you like.  But, it is not a restatement of your OP.  First, your posted answer has several mistakes.  Second, the answer I posted does not rely on the notion of arc length, but rather the notion of the derivative of the arccosine, which can be derived by knowing the derivative of the sine along with the relationship between the derivative of a function and the derivative of its inverse.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really like the heuristic development you wrote but I don't see exactly what you mean, do you have a reference for a picture? Refer to Goldberg Methods of Real Analysis P230 on potential in-built assumptions/contradictions in your use of trigonometric functions, I disagree that I made any errors.

Comment: You're welcome.  My Pleasure.  I don't have a picture but one can easily draw one.  Draw an incremental segment of length $ds$ at a point $s$ on the circle;  this segment is tangent to the circle.  Then draw a small right triangle with sides $dx$ parallel to the x-axis and $dy$ parallel to the $y$-axis.  Now, note that $dx=ds\times \cos \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the angle that $ds$ makes with $dx$.  Then, note finally from the picture that $\cos \gamma = sin(s)$ where $s$ is the angle of the arc on the circle to the segment $ds$.  Since $\sin (s)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, then we are done.